# How to reverse the direction of the qcombobox?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want a QComboBox where the drop down button is on the left and the text is displayed on the right.

Some ascii art to illustrate:

```
+---+------------------------+
| V | ICON     Right Aligned |
+---+------------------------+
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: +1 Very interesting question and applies to other Frameworks besides QT, including Windows and wxWidgets.

Comment: yeah me too waiting for the answer .. post the answer even u find it outside this thread or forum  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

egur's answer is almost correct. This should work:

```
QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
comboBox->addItems(QStringList() << "one" << "two" << "three");
comboBox->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

Comment: Nothing happen to the QComboBox. All lines are aligned left to right

Comment: @Suda.nese The arrow will be on the left side, which is what OP wanted. [Like this](https://i.gyazo.com/9eebaa60f8a4586543886dc47fcb8144.png).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet:

```
comboBox = QComboBox();
view = comboBox.view();
view.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft);
```

Comment: This works to reverse the direction of the drop down choices, but not the combo box itself.